# How to retrieve WPF TabControl's item content?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

I am trying to find a child under a tab control's current selected tab. So far I'm tried things like:

ListView l = UIHelper.FindChild(tabControl.Items[tabControl.SelectedIndex] as MyUserControl, "MyList");

The problem is that the `Items` property and many other properties return the view model, not the template that is being used. How can I access the actual template to find a child?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [TabControl.ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx) property to retrieve the control for a specific tab from the visual tree. If the tab isn't visible, then it might not be able to find it, but for any visible tabs it should be fine.